# Why do the authors use the 'trigraph' to characterize some class of graphs?

Tags: definitions

I have read the series of papers about "the structure of claw-free graphs" (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2008.03.002). Here the authors used the trigraph, that is the adjacency relation contains **three** types:
1 strong adjacent,
2 strong non-adjacent, and 
3 semi-adjacent.

If two vertices $u$ and $v$ are strong adjacent or semi-adjacent, then we say that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent; Similarly, if $u$ and $v$ are strong non-adjacent or semi-adjacent, then we can say that they are non-adjacent.

These papers characterized the structure of claw-free trigraphs. But I am confused to why did the authors use trigraphs?

I think there maybe someone reading these papers and I hope an answer, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?  Why not?  There are many reasons why people might pursue research.  I doubt this is answerable.  You'd have to ask the original authors.  Can you ask an objectively answerable question?

Comment: "As in earlier papers, it is helpful to work with “trigraphs” rather than with graphs": it is likely that the answer is found in a previous article of the series.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your comment. I will consider how to edit this question. Now I am not very clear and I think the answer maybe in a nutshell.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. I have read the preious articles and the link I gave is just an example. In fact, there also are series of papers about "bull-free graphs" and the authors also used the notion "trigraphs". I need more time to understand it and I think it is very important for me.